# Tricky duplicate control: meeting criterias in Excel array formulas

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

A bit of a tricky question - I might just have to do it through VBA with a proper script, however if someone actually has a complicated answer, (let's be honest I don't think there's a super simple formula for this) I'm taker. I'd rather do as much as I can through formulas. I've attached a sample.

The data: I have data that relates to countries. In each country, you can have multiple sites. For each site, you may or not have different distributions. When those distributions meet a given criteria, I want to tally up that as a "break" & count how many by countries, sites, etc.

How it works: I'm using array formulas with sumproduct() for this. The nice thing is that you can easily add criteria, each criteria returns your 0/1 so when you multiply them it gives you the array you need to sum up to see how many breaks you have.

The problem: I am unable to format the formula so that I can account for each site being counted only once in the case where the same site has 2 different distribution types and both meet the break criteria. If both distributions meet the break criteria, I don't want to record that as 2 breaks, otherwise I may end up with more sites with breaks recorded than the number of sites. Part of the problem is how I account for the unicness of sites:

```
(tdata[siteid]>"")/COUNTIF(tdata[siteid],tdata[siteid] &"")
```

This is actually a bit of a hack, in the sense that as opposed to other formulas it doesn't return 0/1 but possibly fractions. They do add up correctly and do allow me to, say, count the number of sites correctly, but the array isn't formated as 0/1 therefore when multiplied with other 0/1 arrays it messes up the results....

I control the data, so I have some leeway. I work with tables (as can be seen) and VBA is already used. I could sort the source tables if that helps. Source data:

1 row = 1 distribution for 1 site on 1 month

The summary table per country I linked is based on those source data.

Any idea?

EDIT - Filtering for distribution is not really an option. I do already have an event-based filters for the source data, and I can already calculate rightly the indicator for filtered data by distributions. But I also need to display global data (which is currently not working). Also there are other indicators that need to be calculate which won't work if I filter the data (it's big dashboard).

EDIT2: In other words, I need to find some way to account for the fact that if the same criteria (break or not) is found in 2 sites with the same siteid but 2 different distributions, I want to count that as 1 break only. While keeping in mind that if one distribution has a break (and the other not), I still want to record it as 1 site with break in that country.

EDIT3: I've decided to make a new table, that summarizes the data for each site individually (each of which may have more than once distribution). Then I can calculate global stuff from that.

My take home message from this: I think that when you have many level of data (e.g. countries, sites, with some kind of a sub-level with distributions) in Excel formulas, it's difficult NOT to summarize the data in intermediate tables for the level of analysis at which you want to focus. E.g. in my case, I am interested in country-level analysis, which is 2 "levels" above the distribution level. This means that there will be "duplication" of data from a site-level perspective. You may be able to navigate around this, but I think by far the simpler solution is to suck it up and make an intermediate table. I does shorten significantly your formulas as well.

I don't mark this as a solution because it's not what I was looking for. Still open to better suggestions allowing to work only with formulas....

File: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ofctha6qhfgtqw/AAD0aPJXr__tononRTpKc1oka?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following can help.

First, you filter the entries which don't meet the criteria regarding the distribution.

In a second step, you sort the table from A to Z based on the column siteid.

Then you add an extra column after the last on with the formula =C3<>C4, where column C contains the siteid entries. In that way all duplicates are denoted by a FALSE value in the helper column.

After that you filter the FALSE values in this column.

You then get unique site ids.

In case I got your question wrong, I would be glad about an update in order to try to help you.

Comment: The problem is that I can't do that if I want to keep formula-based tables. If site A has 2 distributions & both of them have breaks, I can't just filter for NORM (normal) distribution & count that - because site B might have a break just for TRG (targeted) distribution. And I need to count a break for ANY type of distribution withing a site as a break.

There is a dropdown for users to select a specific distribution type already - the problem is that I can't get a global picture currently. There are other indicators as well I need to calculate which won't work with those filters...

Comment: Okay, what about if you start with the second step and leave out the first step then? You then get unique siteids. The selection of the users must then happen prior to the above mentioned steps such that only the wanted distributions are shown. But as long as the filtered results are sorted from A to Z according to siteids the procedure should work?

Comment: Along somewhat similar lines: I actually order (not filter) by the difference between planned & actual numbers (e.g. if it's above a given treshold, it's a break and that's what I want to find out). Then I can use index(match()) to return only the first such match as 1, then the rest as 0.

The problem with that is that it will only work as long as that's the only indicators I need to that for. For now it's ok. If I have new requirements it will breaks it and I'm back at square 1, revisiting the same problem I had 'solved'. If I can't do better, it'll have to be through VBA....